# Random Walk 1D - Variance calculation

Tags: probability, random-walk, variance

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Suppose that a particle starts at the origin of the real line and moves along the line in jumps of one unit
>   (where jumps are independent). For each jump, the probability is p that it jumps one unit to the right and 1 − p that it
>   jumps one unit to the left. Let Xn be the position of the particle after n jumps.

I've calculated the expected value of $X_n$ using $Y_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n $ and $X_n=\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$
so  $E(X_n)=n(2p-1)$ but I'm struggling to calculate $V(X_n)$ !

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the jumps are independent and identically distributed, it follows that
$$ \mathrm{var}(X_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathrm{var}(Y_i)=n\mathrm{var}(Y_1) $$
so you just need to compute the variance of one of the jumps.

Comment: Thanks so as $V(Y_i)= E(Yi^2)-((E(Y_i))^2)$, I think I'm struggling to calculate $E(Yi^2)$

Comment: I have it now : $E(Yi)^2=1$ so $V(Y_i)=1-(2p−1)^2$

Comment: Yes, that's right.